# Check the group membership of the currently logged-on user's Windows credential in C++ and QT

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, active-directory, adsi

So I've done this in C# all the time, and did it with Visual C++ and ADSI back in the day, but I've got a QT C++ project (for a Windows-only target) that needs to get the username and domain of the currently authenticated user and then ask the domain controller whether that user belongs to a handful of specific groups. I had hoped that QT's QAuthenticator class could do this, but it looks like that only does outbound NTLM and can't actually discover anything about existing users -- which brings me back to C++ libraries. Is there a better solution for this than ADSI nowadays? And if not, where do I go to get the ADSI header files now that Technet isn't a thing anymore?